# Should I load 10,000 rows into memory in my Angular app?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm building a customer management tool in Angular.js to load 10,000 customers right into the `$scope`.  From there I can search up and manipulate any of the data without having to make calls to the server (compared to if I just called a small dataset and used pagination).

However now my browser keeps crashing or lagging tremendously once the data is loaded into the scope.  Is the 10,000 customers data loaded into the scope an issue or is there something wrong with my code (when manipulating data such as in cases where I implement auto-suggest)?

Comment: Consider 10000 records in server memory for each thread when you have multiple users accessing the system, this is guaranteed to overload your servers, and is why most people only load the subsets of data that they actually need.... lots of small data volume requests are easily handled by the server, but a few high data volume requests will quickly swamp it

Comment: We cannot help you if you do not post a concise code example.

Comment: It's probably not the raw *size* of the database, but the code you're using to access it.

Comment: have you checked the memory usage? what do you expect us to do without knowing any relevant detail?

Comment: The problem is loading this number of records into JavaScript. Servers can handle this number of records quite easily, but that's a lot of records to send over the wire in one go, and it's a lot of records to hold on the client side. It's worth restarting your browser and then looking at its RAM requirements increase - I suspect you'll find it excessive. Can you reduce this through pagination?

Comment: Paginate and use bindonce, you'll be set.

Comment: I want to implement a auto suggest function as users type in the name of a customer which is why I initially though loading all the records into scope would make it faster compared to making calls to the server everytime a user types a character

Answer (score 1):

1. Putting all in `$scope` could crash
2. It's risky for data

I suggest use direct search using a MySQL query. I just want to mention that 10,000 items is not really a lot of data which take time to find something if it's properly indexed.

Comment: You should not program in code what your database does in a SQL query.

Comment: (Aside for @Usman: please keep material in answers on-topic. It is true that readers are here to help, and that we should be nice to new users, but such material is probably better confined to comments under the question).

Comment: thanks halfer ya u right those should be in comment but its required 50 reputation to comment on question and just wanted to say that :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had to deal with things like this in the past. Lots of data, and if you put it on the scope, then an ng-repeat will kill the browser, as it tries to paint 10,000 nodes. Here is what I did.

I put added a 'limit' variable to the $scope as well:

```
$scope.limit = 20;
```

Then use that limit in your ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="thing in things | limitTo:limit"
```

Then it will only show a certain number of of the 10,000, instead of all of them. This will dramatically improve your performance. Then you will need to add an ng-scroll event that will increase the limit by 10. On the container of your things, add an ng-scroll.

```
<div ng-scroll="increaseLimit()">
    <span ng-repeat="thing in things | limitTo:limit"><!--Your template--></span>
</div>
```

And now implement the increaseLimit method:

```
$scope.increaseLimit = function(){
    $scope.limit += 10;
}
```

This will allow you to have a scroll on your stuff, without killing your page. Let me know what you think.

Another suggestion, if you are doing any filtering of your giant customers array, you should use lodash. Lodash has some insane performance that will allow you to do all of your filtering.